# What's the XDocument equivalent of XmlDocument.ImportNode?

Tags: .net, xml, xmldocument, linq-to-xml

I'm migrating some code from using [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument) to using [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument). As part of this code I need to add an element from one document into another document. With an XmlDocument I could do this using ImportNode, how do I do it with an XDocument?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no equivalent as `XDocument` doesn't have the notion of the document context that `XmlDocument` has.

You can simply add an `XElement` to the document, wherever that element came from.

See [Alternative of `<XMLdocument>.ImportNode`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/0d4ebae8-1d99-49a3-a4d9-a3db0356d48b) on the MSDN forums.